# Zend Module Bootstrap does not load

Tags: zend-framework, module, autoload, bootstrapping

I have a very strange case where my Module is working but my Module's boostrap is not being loaded.

Here is the segment in my application.ini for module autoloading:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = ""
```

Here is the bootstrapper:

```
protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'User_',
            'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH .'/modules/user',
            'resourceTypes' => array (
            'model' => array(
                'path' => 'models',
                'namespace' => 'Model',
                )
            )
        ));
    }
```

Structure of my modules

```
Application
--modules
----user
------config/
------controllers/
------models/
------views/
------Bootstrap.php
----admin
```

The problem here is that User_Bootstrap is not being loaded.

```
<?php

class User_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{

    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        Zend_Registry::set('debug', 'haha');
    }
}
```

By doing a Zend_Registry::get('debug') on any controller, it doesn't recognize that the key was set in the module bootstrap. In fact any syntax error in the User_Bootstrap does not work.

I don't know why User_Bootstrap is not being autoloaded. This is driving me crazy because I've been researching for 5 hours and can't even get a blog post close to covering this case...

Speaking of which, my models and controller classes are being autoloaded fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following...

1. Change your `application.ini` file to use

   ```
   ; lose the quotes
   resources.modules[] =
   ```

   See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.modules
2. Remove the `_initAutoload()` method from your Application `Bootstrap` class. You don't need this as the module bootstrap will automatically create a resource loader for your `User_` classes

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but it might as simple as improper case.
`--Modules` is in your structure but you keep referring to it as `/modules`. These should match case.

I hope it's that simple.

Don't duplicate the function names of your main bootstrap in your module bootstrap, as far as I know in ZF 1.x all of the boostraps get processed every call and I think your _initAutoload in the main boostrap is overriding the module bootstrap.

try calling your function some different like _initModuleAutoload.

 At least worth a shot :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a typo. It is lowercase in my directory. I don't think it should be the problem because the module itself is working. It is loading all the controllers, models, and views. The only thing that is not being loaded is the Bootstrap.

Comment: @DylanSumiskum Check out the edit, might have a possible solution,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling frontController directory in application.ini config file? Try commenting/deleting this line:

`resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"`