# Bootstrap of Zend Module is not loading

Tags: php, zend-framework, autoload

I am new in working with zend so I am facing this problem from the past two days. I have searched a lot but still can not find any solution.

Possible duplicate of [Zend Module Bootstrap does not load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371615/zend-module-bootstrap-does-not-load) but it still can not solve my problem.

In my User module everything is working perfect meaning models dbtables controllers but the Bootstrap.

I just want to add user relevant routes into the user module bootstrap I can also add them into the application bootstrap but I do not want to make it a large file.

I have this in my application/modules/User/Bootstrap.php

```
class User_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initRouter() {
        //does not work i think it should work
        echo 'joo';
        exit;
    }
}
```

As far as I know all bootsrap of modules run every time when we run the application but in my case it doesn't seems to be working.

**Update:**

in my application/configs/application.ini:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = "" 
resources.db.adapter = "Mysqli"
resources.db.params.host = "xxxxx"
resources.db.params.username = "xxxxx"
resources.db.params.password = "xxxxx"
resources.db.params.dbname = "xxxxx"

resources.frontController.actionHelperPaths.Idispatch_Controller_Action_Helper = "Idispatch/Controller/Action/Helper/"
[staging : production]

[testing : production]
resources.cachemanager.database.frontend.options.caching = false
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Bootstrap in my Application directory:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap {
    protected function _initAutoloaders() {
        //user module loader
        new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'User', 'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/User'
        ));

    }
}
```

NOTE: I am using ZFW 1

I came here to ask hoping that someone will help me here. Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong. It will be a great appreciation.

Thanks.

Comment: Is that `resource.modules[] = ""` in your config or just in your question. It should be `resources`

Comment: Yes it was resource.modules[] = "" and I made it resources.modules[] = "" but still Bootstrap does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests in my basic ZF1 setup and the only way this does not work is when the filename is not `Bootstrap.php`. In terms of Linux it is also case sensitive.

As you mention correctly the modules path is looked at every time and `exit()` is working in my case. Except the file doesn't exist or with the misspelling in the config which you say you fixed.

Also you shouldn't need the Autoloader in your main bootstrap but I checked and it doesn't cause this issue.

Comment: Hi. Please take a look on the question again please, I have update and added some more information. Hope it helps. And yes I have removed the Autoloader in my main bootstrap and modules still work but bootstrap does not.

Comment: Well you say for your User module everything is working just not the Bootstrap file. Then your setup must be correct but something must be wrong with that file and as I wrote most likely the spelling of the filename. Note that for ZF1 it is good practice to have a bootstrap file inside a module but it's not required.

Comment: Got you! Beat me! The permissions was not set i made it 777 and it worked! Damn! I am so fool!!!! Thanks man! you gave the point!

Comment: Ahyes the permissions ;-) glad to help

Comment: Thanks again! Feel sooo foolish! been hitting my head from 2 days!